Order products by product_type.name in Rails
I have Product and ProductType
class ProductType < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product_type

    def type_name
        self.product_type.name
    end
end

I can use "type_name" in Product index view to show the product type for each product



Code
Name
Type_Name




P0001
Croissant
Viennoiserie


p0002
Sacher Torte
Cakes


P0003
Brioche pistachio
Viennoiserie


P0004
Choux chocolate
Choux


.....
.............
.........



but I cannot use type_name to have a Product collection ordered by type_name like this



Code
Name
Type_Name




p0002
Sacher Torte
Cakes


P0004
Choux chocolate
Choux


P0001
Croissant
Viennoiserie


P0003
Brioche pistachio
Viennoiserie


.....
.............
.........



I tried to search both S.O. and google  in general but it seems very few have this quite common problem, and I tried the proposed solutions (using scope or Arel) but with no success

Did you try a basic search for "Rails order by joined column?".

Yes, tried this exact search and a number of variations, and got the useless (for me)answers about using "scope" or Arel

Solution is
Product.joins(:product_type).order('product_types.name ASC')

Starting with Rails 7.2 you can use a hash instead - .order(product_types: { name: :asc }).

@Anton Thanks a lot, it is so simple I do not realize how I didn't find it in the Rails Guides...
